# Spring Boot environment and profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, production-environment

I don't what is the most secured pattern to follow. Should `application.properties` be the prod configuration and create a `application-dev.properties` for development?

Or the opposite, `application.properties` for dev and `application-prod.properties` for production?

Or a mix of both, having both `application-prod.properties` and `application-dev.properties`?

Answer (score 2):

Spring will load the default `application.properties` file **for every profile enabled**.

Then the profile specific property file (ex `application-dev.properties`) is loaded and merged into the properties of the spring context.

So I think the best approach is:

- use the default `application.properties` file for properties that are common between different profiles.
- use specific property files ex `application-dev.properties` to define properties that are separate between environments.

Also as [per documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) properties defined in profile specific application property file, are able to override properties defined under the default `application.properties` file. This here is what opens the door for what you mention like, having for production the default `application.properties` file and then each environment using it's own profile property file since that way the profile specific property file will override the properties declared in the default `application.properties`.

But I think that the first approach I mentioned is more clean.

Answer (score 1):

I think I saw all of those patterns in different projects. Even I can list couple more. All of them were enterprise level projects developed by mature teams.

**Rather than naming patterns, there is another practice which is most important: Never include any sensitive data in codebase.**

If you use yaml or property file, if you choose a naming pattern etc is just matter of choice and implementation.

Comment: OK thanks. So where can I put my database connection password if not in application-prod.properties ?

Comment: There are various ways to achieve it too. Most practical and common ones are injecting them through the CI/CD process or reading those values within application server as an environment variable.